# I am having trouble getting this code to work? This code is suppoed to find out how long it took for the program for fing d[42] This is a python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, time, zip

When I try to run this code I am supposed to get values for the time time it took the program to located[42] but I keep getting an erroe

```
import random
import time

ranges = [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]

dict_times = []
index_times = []
sort_times = []

for i in ranges:

    L = random.sample(range(i), i)
    d = dict(zip(L,L))

    #time for dict ------

    #start the time here
    start = time.time()

    v = d[42]

    #end the time here
    end = time.time()

    dict_times.append(end-start)

    #time for index ------

    #start the time here
    start = time.time()

    ind = L.index(42)

    #end the time here
    end = time.time()

    index_times.append(end-start)

    #time for sort -----

    #start the time here
    start = time.time()

    L = sorted(L)

    #end the time here
    end = time.time()

    sort_times.append(end-start)

print('Times for dictionary lookup:', dict_times, end="\n\n")

print('Times for list lookup:', index_times)
index_ratios = [round(index_times[i]/index_times[i-1], 2) for i in range(1, len(index_times))]
print('List lookup Ratios:', index_ratios, end="\n\n")


print('Times for list sort:', sort_times)
sort_ratios = [round(sort_times[i]/sort_times[i-1], 2) for i in range(1, len(sort_times))]
print('List sort Ratios:', sort_ratios, end="\n\n")

list_sort_over_index = [round(sort_times[i]/index_times[i], 2) for i in range(len(sort_times))]
print('List sort over list lookup:', list_sort_over_index, end="\n\n")
```

The error I get is:
line 57, in 
index_ratios = [round(index_times[i]/index_times[i-1], 2) for i in range(1, len(index_times)
The full error I get is:

runfile('C:/Users/sanil/OneDrive/Desktop/Business App Developement/hw9/turnin/hw09.py.py', wdir='C:/Users/sanil/OneDrive/Desktop/Business App Developement/hw9/turnin', current_namespace=True)
Times for dictionary lookup: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Times for list lookup: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03130626678466797]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\sanil\OneDrive\Desktop\Business App Developement\hw9\turnin\hw09.py.py", line 57, in 
index_ratios = [round(index_times[i]/index_times[i-1], 2) for i in range(1, len(index_times))]

File "C:\Users\sanil\OneDrive\Desktop\Business App Developement\hw9\turnin\hw09.py.py", line 57, in 
index_ratios = [round(index_times[i]/index_times[i-1], 2) for i in range(1, len(index_times))]

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
I am running this code in sypder, am I missing any plug ins in the application, no matter how many times I run the code I am getting the same error

Comment: Please post the full error message, starting from the word `Traceback`.

Comment: I did a copy/paste of your code into my IDE and executed it successfully without any need for modification (Python 3.10.4 and VS Code)

Comment: Same here @LancelotduLac

Comment: @Sunny Try using `time.perf_counter()` instead by replacing all instances of `time.time()` in your code with `time.perf_counter()`. From the `time.time()` documentation: "[n]ote that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second". That probably explains why you get 0s as you are subtracting low precision times over very fast operations.

Comment: replacing all the time.time() to time.perf_counter() worked. Thank you so much oda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `time.perf_counter()` by replacing all instances of `time.time()` in your code with `time.perf_counter()`.

From the `time.time()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time),

> [n]ote that even though the time is always returned as a floating
> point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision
> than 1 second.

That probably explains why you get 0s as you are subtracting low precision times over very fast operations.